# How to fix ActiveMQ Artemis connection timeouts when sslEnabled=true

Tags: ssl, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to enable SSL on a Artemis broker and always get this exception when trying to connect:

```
Exception in thread "main" ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=AMQ219013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:743)
```

The code I use to connect is just this:

```java
ActiveMQClient.createServerLocator("tcp://localhost:5500").createSessionFactory();
```

This is from a fresh install of Artemis 2.23.1 and the only thing I changed from the default broker configuration was to add this `acceptor` in `broker.xml`:

```xml
<acceptor name="netty-ssl-acceptor">tcp://localhost:5500?sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=server-keystore.jks;keyStorePassword=securepass</acceptor>
```

I generated the keystore and truststore using the script provided in [this example](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/main/examples/features/standard/ssl-enabled).

I had first tried a keystore with a cert that is valid for my domain (using a domain-qualified host name in `createServerLocator()`) but that also gave me the timeout.  That is when I went back to fresh installs and tried going through the SSL example.

Various attempts with invalid paths/passwords/certs threw exceptions that led me to what to fix, but so far haven't been able to see what I did wrong with a generic timeout discovering cluster topology.

Anybody have ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `sslEnabled=true` on the client's URL as well so it knows to use SSL, e.g.:

```java
ActiveMQClient.createServerLocator("tcp://localhost:5500?sslEnabled=true").createSessionFactory();
```

This is done for the JMS connection in the `ssl-enabled` example which you cited [here](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/main/examples/features/standard/ssl-enabled/src/main/resources/jndi.properties).

Also, if you're using self-signed certificates then you'll need a truststore for your client as well and you'll need to configure those settings on the client's URL (just like in the example).